# mat-select in a for-loop, setting the "selected" in dropdown - angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, templates, angular-material

I am looping through my "menuOptions" in my html in order to output multiple options in a dropdown menu within a mat-accoridion (an angular material api)

i want the value to be the value on every select drop down, so i set my [(value)] to the element in my for loop (shown below)

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of menuOptions" [value]="option" (click)="selectConfig(option)">
      {{option}}
</mat-option>
```

However, I want one to be autoselected on my first load.... (the first menu option in the array menuOption autoselected) i can't just set option in my typescript file because i only have menuOptions (array) available. option is the element i'm looping over in my for loop.

Any ideas how to set the option another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The selected value needs to be defined in the enclosing `mat-select` element.

```
<mat-select [value]="selectedMenuOption">
```

This presumes you have a public member named `selectedMenuOption` in your component.

When defining two-way binding through `[(value)]`, you can even get rid of the `click` event handler defined for your `mat-option` elements.

```
<mat-select [(value)]="selectedMenuOption">
```

The following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rnlrldkxbyk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts) from [Angular Material Examples](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples) nicely illustrates this.

Comment: I've seen this - but the difference between mine and the code that you attached is that mine is in a for loop... so "option" -- in my example above  -- is not a real variable. it's temporary as it loops through my select option values. Therefore, this does not work for me.

Comment: how? i can't do option = "Example" if option is an element in my ngFor of menuOptions

Comment: It's hard to give advise without seeing the code and little more of the template. Maybe you can provide a StackBlitz with what you already have, then it will be easier to find a viable solution.